# Firebase functions with Algolia doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, algolia

Good evening, while starting with Algolia and Firestore I ran into an issue while trying to set a function. This function will create a record every time a new document is added in firestore.

This is the code in typescript

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();
const fcm = admin.messaging();
const env = functions.config();

import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch';

const client = algoliasearch(env.algolia.appid, env.algolia.apikey);
const groupIndex = client.initIndex('group_names');

exports.onGroupCreated = functions.firestore.document('Groups/{GroupId}').onCreate( async (snap, context) => {

  const note = snap.data();

  note.objectID = snap.id;

  return await groupIndex.saveObject(note).catch(err => console.error(err));
});
```

[image]

Here is the log :

```
2020-06-26T15:04:13.261462987Z D onGroupCreated: Function execution started
2020-06-26T15:04:13.261518259Z D onGroupCreated: Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions
2020-06-26T15:04:13.870Z ? onGroupCreated: undefined
2020-06-26T15:04:13.876475187Z D onGroupCreated: Function execution took 616 ms, finished with status: 'error'
```

I know the problem is not the billing account because the function worked one time and other functions which are fires on onCreate work fine.

This is the log obtained after adding await in return.

```
2020-06-27T16:25:26.874631529Z D onGroupCreated: Function execution started
2020-06-27T16:25:26.874688858Z D onGroupCreated: Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions
2020-06-27T16:25:27.411Z ? onGroupCreated:   message:
2020-06-27T16:25:27.411Z ? onGroupCreated: { name: 'RetryError',
2020-06-27T16:25:27.411Z ? onGroupCreated:    'Unreachable hosts - your application id may be incorrect. If the error persists, contact support@algolia.com.',
2020-06-27T16:25:27.411Z ? onGroupCreated:   transporterStackTrace:
2020-06-27T16:25:27.411Z ? onGroupCreated:    [ { request: [Object],
2020-06-27T16:25:27.411Z ? onGroupCreated:        response: [Object],
2020-06-27T16:25:27.411Z ? onGroupCreated:        host: [Object],
2020-06-27T16:25:27.411Z ? onGroupCreated:        triesLeft: 3 },
2020-06-27T16:25:27.411Z ? onGroupCreated:      { request: [Object],
2020-06-27T16:25:27.411Z ? onGroupCreated:        response: [Object],
2020-06-27T16:25:27.411Z ? onGroupCreated:        host: [Object],
2020-06-27T16:25:27.411Z ? onGroupCreated:        triesLeft: 2 },
2020-06-27T16:25:27.411Z ? onGroupCreated:      { request: [Object],
2020-06-27T16:25:27.411Z ? onGroupCreated:        response: [Object],
2020-06-27T16:25:27.411Z ? onGroupCreated:        host: [Object],
2020-06-27T16:25:27.411Z ? onGroupCreated:        triesLeft: 1 },
2020-06-27T16:25:27.411Z ? onGroupCreated:      { request: [Object],
2020-06-27T16:25:27.411Z ? onGroupCreated:        response: [Object],
2020-06-27T16:25:27.411Z ? onGroupCreated:        host: [Object],
2020-06-27T16:25:27.411Z ? onGroupCreated:        triesLeft: 0 } ] }
2020-06-27T16:25:27.415997358Z D onGroupCreated: Function execution took 542 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
```

Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: Seems fine. Can you post the error stack from Firebase logs?

Comment: Hello, I have updated my post.

Comment: which plan are u using? are you 100% positive you are not using Spark?

Comment: I found that sending the whole object to Algolia is not a good idea, cause it has a size limit. Try to add await before the saveObject and catch to see if there is an issue with Algolia: `return await groupIndex.saveObject(note).catch(err => console.error(err));`

Comment: andresmijares I am sure because I don't want to pay for firebase.

Comment: Santi Barbat I have updated my post

Comment: I think @andresmijares is right with its question. It looks like you're using the Spark plan in Firebase (the free one). Outbound request are only allowed in GCP services so not Algolia.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the fn is returning undefined, try this instead, It's possible your context is not working the way you are expecting

```
exports.onGroupCreated = functions.firestore.document('Groups/{GroupId}').onCreate( async (snap, context) => {

  const note = snap.data();

  note.objectID = snap.id; // <<---- here

  return groupIndex.saveObject(note);
});
```

The `snap.id` prop will get you the underline id of the document. At least the documentation is clear.

Also, make you are not using the Spark plan, it doesn't allow the outbound connection (even if you see it working a few cases).

Comment: Is there a reason why is "more reliable than using context"? Cheers.

Comment: I have modified my post with your suggestion. Now it is returning 'ok' but can't reach algolia although I am 100% using the right credentials. Moreover I absolutely don't want to pay for firebase.

Comment: if you are using the Spark plan as I mentioned, it's not going to work, it doesn't support outbound connection, I suggest to check the free tier, maybe it's good enough for your case, otherwise, maybe this is not the right solution for your case. Best!

Comment: @SantiBarbat personal opinion, but you are right, it's a wide-open assumption